# Migrate Jooma Users to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, joomla, migration

We are running a Joomla website and recently integrated SharePoint to our office. 
Does anyone have a recommendation on how to migrate Joomla (website) registered users to SharePoint?  (so users have the same username/password on both systems).

Comment: http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=sharepoint

Comment: @Lodder That extension only works if the data is in SharePoint and you want to migrate it to Joomla.  I would like to do the opposite (Joomla to SharePoint).  Here's a response from customer service to my questions: "To have the same username/password on SharePoint and Joomla the user need to reside in a Membership system mastered by SharePoint so the way you planned to use it won't work with our product."